# I am converting my existing firebase/react project to typescript. How can I batch.update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

currently getting a typescript error on batch.update that I just cannot fix.

```
const batch = db.batch();
              const listingDoc = await db.collection("listings").doc(listingID).get();
              const listingData = listingDoc.data() as Listing;
              if (listingData.status === "listed") {
                batch.update(
                  listingDoc,
                  {
                    status: currentUser.uid,
                  },
                  { merge: true }
                );
...
```

The error I get is:

```
Argument of type '{ status: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FieldPath'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'status' does not exist in type 'FieldPath'.ts(2345)
(property) status: string
```

I am supposed to give the `"status"` field the firebase.firestore.fieldpath type? Unsure how to do that in the actual batch.update.

TIA!

Comment: On further inspection.  it seems the {merge: true} is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have more than two arguments to `.update()` , firestore assumes you are using the "variable number of arguments" format, which consists of :

```
batch.update(DocumenrReference, FieldPath, Value, FieldPath, Value,...)
```

`.update()` does not HAVE an options argument, especially since merge is ASSUMED in an update.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#update

Comment: Correct, I must of mistaken it for .set(). Thank you!